# Ruby On Rails session storage problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im creating a sample RUBY ON RAILS APP and storing sessions in DB

The table structure is 
id:pk,autoincrement

session_id:varchar 256

data:longtext

When i click save i get following error:

"Your session data is larger than the data column in which it is to be stored. You must increase the size of your data column if you intend to store large data."

Comment: `longtext` has a max size of 4GBs, what are you storing in your sessions that it doesn't fit in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question itself has the answer. Just increase the size of `data:longtext` which is `data column`